# Changing inner HTML of a button with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, html

On a project I'm working on, a HTML file is defining a Javascript template used on selection buttons.  All buttons have a "Change..." label that I want to localize (set dynamically).  In other cases I'm searching for the element ID and setting the InnerHTML accordingly.  But in this case, the ID of the buttons are defined dynamically.  Is it possible to have a text element inside the button element, search for this element, and set its InnerHTML value?

```
<script id="optionSelectionTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="sub-section option-selection">
        {{#if name}}<h4>{{name}}</h4>{{/if}}
        <div class="current"></div><button class="button" id="{{id}}" data-action-id="{{id}}">Change...</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

I've been searching this for a while now.  But given that my forte is not web development, I'm not really sure what to search for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get the button element(s) by its class instead; for example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
```

As you suggested, you can improve your selection's precision by first getting the 'optionSelectionTemplate' element(s) like so:

```
var x = document.getElementById("optionSelectionTemplate").getElementsByClassName("button");
```

Or if you prefer:

```
var x = document.getElementById("optionSelectionTemplate").getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Here are some links for more on these method:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: A little risky, since there might be more than one type of button on the page, isn't it?  Is it possible to combine with finding all the "optionSelectionTemplate" elements first, and then searching for the "button" class inside?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there could be risk, sure.  I've updated my answer with your suggestion on finding the optionSelectionTemplate elements first.

Comment: Why not just adding a second class, i.e. `<button class="button localize" >...`? Then, searching for the `localize` class would only turn up the relevant items.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how dynamic your localization should become, you could also specify the text inside a (locale-dependent) CSS as in https://jsfiddle.net/1gws5kat/ :

```
[HTML]
<button class="button btn_change" id="{{id}}" data-action-id="{{id}}"></button>
[CSS]
.btn_change:before { content: "Change..."; }
```

In particular when dealing with a large number of identically-named elements (i.e. many "Change" buttons), this might be pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

You find those btns by this command:

var btnlist= $(':button')
This Camano get you all button in your html file, then loop ton in and apply your changing.
 Before call this command, jquery must be install.